# How to change default download location in android

Tags: android

I have a webview and i want to download files to the sdcard custom folder when user clicking download link from webview.

I'm using the following code for downloading file from webview:

```
webView.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {
  public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
    long contentLength) {
    strurl = url;

    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        i.setData(Uri.parse(url));

startActivity(i);
}
```

It works properly. But it directly downloads to the `/sdcard/download/` folder. But i want it to download to some other folder on the sdcard. How can I accomplish this?